# SQL add unique index in scope of two datetime's

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an table calles SpecialOffer with productId, shopId, from , until , where the last two ones are datetime's.

I know i can do something like this

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UniqueIndex2 ON SpecialOffer(codP, codS)
```

for codP to be uniq in scope of codS, but how can I accomplish this uniqueness only between 'from' and 'until' ?

Comment: There is no way to do this with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this with triggers -- insert and update trigger.  These can check for overlaps in the time periods.

In general, in MySQL, most constraints are handled through triggers (except for unique constraints and foreign key constraints).